# Django Static Folder Forbidden (403) on Nginx Digital Ocean

Tags: django, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I've successfully followed this tutorial on digital ocean: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04

on deploying a django app - the app works fine but one thing I noticed is that the app can't render styles in the static folder - it returns a 403. Am I missing something? Is it a server issue or do I need to configure something additionally in Django.

Please note if I run `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` the styles render fine.

Comment: try giving chmod permissions to static folder. I already have this issue

Comment: I've tried sudo chmod -R 755 /home/user/myapp/static but I get the same issue. Is there a specific way to do it?

Comment: I ran chmod 0777 and works.

Comment: If 777 works, you have an issue with the owner user of your app folder

Comment: @Alexa, did you manage to solve the problem? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @Alexa did you manage to solve the problem eventually ,cause I am currently stuck  with the same issue.a detail process to fix the problem would be a wonderful help

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a problem where my js modules imported another module and the imported module was not loading with a `403 forbidden` message.  This was because in my django's `settings.py` I did not include ````` AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'```` So they were private resources.  Once the permssion is set to public-read, the ````` 403 Forbidden``` error goes away.  See [the docs here](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html)